# gsutil hangs on large file

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gsutil

I'm uploading a file that is 8.6T in size.

```
$ nohup gsutil -o GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M cp big_file.jsonl gs://bucket/big_file.jsonl > nohup.mv-big-file.out 2>&1 &
```

At some point, it just hangs, with no error messages, nothing.

Any suggestions on how I can move this large file from the box to the GS bucket?

Comment: 1) Unless you have a dedicated gigabit Internet connection, uploading 8 TB will take months to complete. 2) The maximum Google Cloud Storage object size is 5 TB. You cannot complete the upload of 8.6 TB successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In accordance to what @John Hanley mentioned, the maximum size limit for individual objects stored in Cloud Storage is 5 TB, as stated in [Buckets and Objects Limits](https://cloud.google.com/storage/quotas#buckets:%7E:text=There%20is%20a%20maximum%20size%20limit%20for%20individual%20objects%20stored%20in%20Cloud%20Storage.%20This%20limit%20is%205%20TiB.)

Here are some workaround that you can try :

1. You can try uploading it across multiple folders on a single bucket since there is no limit on the actual bucket size.
2. Second option you can try is chunking of your files up to 32 chunks [Parallel composite uploads](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/parallel-composite-uploads).
3. Another option that you may also consider is [Transfer Appliance](https://cloud.google.com/transfer-appliance/docs/4.0/overview?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-PH-all-en-dr-bkws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009882&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_284325740114-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Migration%20%7E%20Transfer%20Appliance_transfer%20appliance-KWID_43700035200375316-aud-1644542956068%3Akwd-475861321120&userloc_9067371-network_g&utm_term=KW_gcp%20transfer%20appliance&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIlYrjxMbZ-gIVE4ZLBR0rhQrTEAAYASAAEgLdhvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds#:%7E:text=bookmark_border-,Transfer%20Appliance,-is%20a%20high) for a faster and higher capacity of upload to Cloud Storage.

You might want to take a look as well to GCS's [best practices](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/best-practices) documentation.